# How does using 'apt-get install' affect reverse dependencies?

Tags: apt

If libfoo is pulled in by the package bar, and I upgrade it by executing `apt-get install libfoo`, how will this affect reverse dependencies?

If I then remove the package bar, will libfoo still be removed by `apt-get autoremove`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you run `apt-get install libfoo` it will mark it as manually installed. This means it won't be removed by autoremove.

And as far as I know, running `apt-get install libfoo` won't upgrade `libfoo`. It's already installed as a dependency of `bar` and it'll automatically be the most updated version that it can be (while still compatible with `bar`).

If there's a newer version of `libfoo` that isn't compatible with `bar`'s dependency (packages can state what version of a package they need including "newer than x" or "older than x"), `libfoo` will be held back.

Comment: For libraries there's also the policy statement that a newer libfoo must not break any rdepends.  Any time the library changes ABI it should also change SONAME, and we mandate that the SONAME be included in the package name (which is why you'll sometimes see libfoo1 and libfoo2 in the archive at the same time).

Answer (score 1):

1) If libfoo is a dependence, doing `apt-get install libfoo` will install only the version compatible with the other application using it.

2) If you remove **bar** and no other application is using **libfoo**, it will be removable with `apt-get autoremove`.

Comment: These aren't necessarily true, and the second point is false.  If you've run “apt-get install libfoo” then libfoo is marked as manually installed and isn't a candidate for autoremove.